# Forms created through buddyforms don't have the code snippet that other options have in member profile page in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, buddypress

I have a page which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjtrf.jpg) and the code for the highlighted part is this.

This file is located at buddypress/members/single/home.php

```
<div id="item-nav">
        <div class="item-list-tabs no-ajax" id="object-nav" role="navigation">
            <ul id="nav-bar-filter">
<?php bp_get_displayed_user_nav();

     do_action( 'bp_member_options_nav' ); ?>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The code for the function bp_get_displayed_user_nav is and its location is buddypress/bp-members/bp-members-template.php

```
function bp_get_displayed_user_nav() {
$bp = buddypress();
foreach ( $bp->members->nav->get_primary() as $user_nav_item ) {
    if ( empty( $user_nav_item->show_for_displayed_user ) && ! bp_is_my_profile() ) {
        continue;
    }
    $selected = '';
    if ( bp_is_current_component( $user_nav_item->slug ) ) {
        $selected = ' class="current selected"';
    }
    if ( bp_loggedin_user_domain() ) {
        $link = str_replace( bp_loggedin_user_domain(), bp_displayed_user_domain(), $user_nav_item->link );
    } else {
        $link = trailingslashit( bp_displayed_user_domain() . $user_nav_item->link );
    }
    /**
     * Filters the navigation markup for the displayed user.
     *
     * This is a dynamic filter that is dependent on the navigation tab component being rendered.
     *
     * @since 1.1.0
     *
     * @param string $value         Markup for the tab list item including link.
     * @param array  $user_nav_item Array holding parts used to construct tab list item.
     *                              Passed by reference.
     */
    echo apply_filters_ref_array( 'bp_get_displayed_user_nav_' . $user_nav_item->css_id, array( '<li id="' . $user_nav_item->css_id . '-personal-li" ' . $selected . '><a id="user-' . $user_nav_item->css_id . '" href="' . $link . '">' . $user_nav_item->name . '</a></li>', &$user_nav_item ) );
}
}
```

HTML is

```
<div id="item-nav">
<div class="item-list-tabs no-ajax" id="object-nav" role="navigation">
<ul id="nav-bar-filter" class="horizontal-responsive-menu">

    <li class="hideshow"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
        <ul>
            <li id="activity-personal-li" class="current selected" style=""><a id="user-activity" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/activity/">Wall</a></li>
            <li id="xprofile-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-xprofile" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/profile/">Profile</a></li>
            <li id="articles-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-articles" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/articles/">Articles <span>0</span></a></li>
            <li id="requests-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-requests" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/requests/">Requests <span>1</span></a></li>
            <li id="tour-packages-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-tour-packages" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/tour-packages/">Tour Packages <span>0</span></a></li>
            <li id="messages-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-messages" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/messages/">Messages <span class="no-count">0</span></a></li>
            <li id="friends-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-friends" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/friends/">Friends <span class="count">1</span></a></li>
            <li id="mediapress-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-mediapress" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/mediapress/">Gallery <span>0</span></a></li>
            <li id="settings-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-settings" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/settings/">Settings</a></li>
            <li id="invite-anyone-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-invite-anyone" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/invite-anyone/">Send Invites</a></li>
            <li id="notifications-personal-li" style=""><a id="user-notifications" href="https://www.tourpeer.com/members/kushal/notifications/">Notifications <span class="no-count">0</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have created two forms Articles and Requests through buddyforms, when they are no articles or requests it works fine but whenever there is an article or a request, the left side navigation bar looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUJ9G.jpg).

I have found out that the reason behind this is that whenever there is a request or an article this code snippet gets missing from the html

```
<li class="hideshow"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a></l>
```

I couldn't figure out why this is happening, please help me fix this.

Comment: Depending on the kind of page you visit, different kind of code snippets may be used. You mentioned `buddypress/members/single/home.php`. This template will be used whenever you visit the homepage. That means you will have to take a look at the template (possibly) located at `buddypress/members/single/archive.php` or `buddypress/members/single/single.php`.

Comment: There are no files that you have named. The Articles and Requests are a part of the home page only.